# How to highlight text when edittext gets focused?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

In my android app, I have a bunch of edititexts that's a numeric keyboard. On the keyboard is a next key, which when clicked moves the cursor to the next edittext. How can I make it highlight the text of the new focused edit text when the next key is clicked? Basically I want to just click next, then type some new numbers which replaces the old one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        if(hasFocus)
        { 
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
        }
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your EditText on xml:

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```